# Taurus Proxy Issue

Tags: selenium, jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

I am using Taurus for first time. I am configuring the same on windows. I have installed Taurus and trying to convert Selenium to Jmeter Script. I am following the below reference

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter/

I have set up proxy in blazemeter and put the same in .bzt.rc file and also placed the secret ID and token.

I have tried with multiple ways to configure proxy2jmx and after several changes now i am able to execute the selenium test where the browser opens and the selenium transactions executes. I get the smartjmx, but with no transaction recorded.

Below is my .bzt-rc file

```
# General Settings

settings:
#  default-executor: jmeter  # if you prefer using other executor by default - change this option
#  artifacts-dir: ~/bzt-artifacts/%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%f  # change the default place to store artifact files
#  check-updates: true  # check for newer version of Taurus on startup
#  check-interval: 1s  # interval for Taurus engine to check test status and do other actions
#  proxy:
#   address: http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#    username: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#    password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

---

# CLI aliases - configure your "shortcuts" to apply config pieces

#cli-aliases:  # user-defined config pieces to apply from command-line
#  debug:  # this alias is called as '-debug' from command line
#    settings:
#      verbose: true
#    modules:
#      jmeter:
#        gui: true
#      console:
#         disable: true

---

# BlazeMeter reporting settings

modules:
  blazemeter:
    token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#
#    test: Test Name  # name for test to store reports
#    project: Project Name  # name for project to store test, can be numeric project ID
#    public-report: false  # set to true to create a public link to the report
#
#    browser-open: start  # auto-open the report in browser,
#                         # can be "start", "end", "both", "none"
#    send-interval: 30s   # send data each n-th second
#    timeout: 5s  # connect and request timeout for BlazeMeter API
#    artifact-upload-size-limit: 10  # limit max size of file (in megabytes)
#                                   # that goes into zip for artifact upload, 10 by default
#    check-interval: 5s  # interval which Taurus uses to query test status from BlazeMeter

---

# JMeter settings

#modules:
#  jmeter:
#    properties:  # JMeter properties for every JMeter run
#      prop_name: prop value
#    system-properties:  # Java system properties
#      sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders: "true"
#    memory-xmx: 4G  # allow JMeter to use up to 4G of memory
#    path: ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/{version}/bin/jmeter  # path to local jmeter installation
#    version: 3.2  # version to use
#    plugins:  # plugins to install
#    - jpgc-json=2.2
#    - jmeter-ftp
#    - jpgc-casutg

---

# Gatling settings

#modules:
#  gatling:
#    properties:
#      gatling.data.file.bufferSize: 256 # output buffer size, 256 bytes by default
```

I am getting the below error in log file

[2019-09-07 16:35:16,014 WARNING Engine.proxy2jmx] There aren't requests recorded by proxy2jmx, check your proxy configuration
[2019-09-07 16:35:16,022 WARNING Engine.proxy2jmx] Problems with chrome tuning are encountered, take look at http://gettaurus.org/docs/Proxy2JMX/ for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove these `#` characters from the beginning of the lines. As per [YAML Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Syntax) article:

> - Comments begin with the number sign (`#`), can start anywhere on a line and continue until the end of the line. Comments must be separated from other tokens by whitespace characters.[15] If # characters appear inside of a string, then they are number sign (#) literals.

You can also try reaching out to Taurus developers via [codename-taurus](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/codename-taurus) forums or if you're a BlazeMeter customer you can open a [support ticket](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-open-a-support-ticket-)

And last but not the least, you can [configure your Selenium tests to use JMeter as the proxy](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy) and perform the recording using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. 
I think # is not the issue, else i would have not able to run Taurus.
Also I have to do all the recording operations on command line and as i am aware about Jmeter test script recorder cannot be initiated as non-gui mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error. I was working on the same tutorial on a Windows machine. From
[this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/codename-taurus/There$20aren$27t$20requests$20recorded$20by$20proxy2jmx$2C$20check$20your$20proxy$20configuration%7Csort:date/codename-taurus/Gf1HzQSdI5Q/6LYA4hOHAAAJ) post, and came I across this statement:

> Sorry, only Chrome is supported on Windows.

So, I changed the example files to include ChromeDriver instead of FirefoxDriver and it worked for me.